# python creating dictionary from excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns. Column 1 is name, and Column 2 is age. I want to create a dictionary where name is key and age is value. Here is the code, but it is creating a dictionary incorrectly.

```
keyValues = [x.value for x in worksheet.col(0)]
data = dict((x, []) for x in keyValues)
while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1
        for row_index in range(1, worksheet.nrows):  data[keyValues[row_index]].append(worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, 1))
```

I want to have a dictionary like below coming from 2 columns of excel sheet.

```
{'Ann': 12, 'Maria': 3, 'Robin': 4, 'NameN':N}
```

Answer (score 7):

That's quite simple with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dic = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict()
```

my_dic is now:

{'Robin': 4, 'Maria': 3, 'Ann': 12}

`index_col=0` if 'name' is in the first column of your excel file

Comment: Hej! I would get {12: {'Maria': 3, 'Robin': 4}}. Do you know what my problem could be? @Marek

Answer (score 0):

If your columns don't contain any data other than the names and ages and you're pretty confident about the data quality (no non-numeric data where ages should be, etc.) then you could go about it something like this:

```
names = (name.value for name in worksheet.col(0))
ages = (int(age.value) for age in worksheet.col(1))
data = dict(zip(names, ages))
```

If you want to guarantee order, you could use a `collections.OrderedDict` object for `data` instead of a vanilla dictionary.

If you need to handle bad data (i.e. someone entered a string instead of an integer age in the sheet), you may have to come up with custom implementations of the `names` and `ages` generator objects (the ones above assume smooth sailing).