# Getting data from Excel into a Shelve (Python3)

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have come across a Python module for reading Apple serial numbers and gift ving back the product type. Please see [Mac Model Shelf](https://github.com/MagerValp/MacModelShelf)

It's very powerful and has a vast a catalogue of product types - some stuff going well back into the 90's. Slightly overkill for my purposes. The results it gives back tend to be a little vague (for new macs at least). No processor type, speed etc.

I have decided to re-write it slightly with my own database of serial numbers and corresponding machine types.

E.g "W88010010P2" will give back "Black Macbook 2008 2GHz - PG 1001", for the sake of the example. The 'PG' stands for Product Group, the reference code I use to find identical macs in my Filemaker database.

```
import shelve
databaseOfMacs = shelve.open("macmodelshelfNEW")
inputSerial = "W88010010P2"
modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = ""

#extracting the model code. 3 digits for older macs, 4 for newer
#newer macs have 12 digits, older ones just 11
if len(inputSerial) == 12:
    modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = inputSerial[-4:]
elif len(inputSerial) == 11:
 modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial = inputSerial[-3:]

#setting a key-value pair, for the sake of example
databaseOfMacs['0P2'] = "Black Macbook 2008 2GHz - PG 1001"

model = databaseOfMacs[modelCodeIsolatedFromSerial]
print model
```

This will produce as the output...

```
Black Macbook 2008 2GHz - PG 1001

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Adding key-value pairs inside the script is not practical. I have started to build up an Excel (xlsx) file of the key-value pairs of model codes and their actual descriptions. Just two columns.

```
A    B
0P2  Black Macbook 2008 2GHz - PG 1001
G8WP MacBook Pro 205Ghz i7 (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) - PG 786
```

I have searched online on SO but cannot find a clean way of getting this data into the shelve file. The suggested solutions are importing the values into a dictionary and after the fact, importing the dictionary into the shelve. I am getting stuck on just the first part, errant '0's are getting into the dictionary, based on [python creating dictionary from excel
,stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414635/python-creating-dictionary-from-excel)

If this could be condensed into a single step it would change everything!

Thanks for any help which is given.

**UPDATE**

I think I have figured it out myself... just the getting the excel data into a shelve...

```
import pandas as pd
import shelve

excelDict = pd.read_excel('serials_and_models.xlsx', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True).to_dict()
excelMacDataBaseShelve = shelve.open("excelMacDataBaseShelve")
excelMacDataBaseShelve.update(excelDict)

# to verify all is well
for key in excelMacDataBaseShelve:
    print(key, excelMacDataBaseShelve[key])
```

The wonderful thing about shelves is that I can just update the excel file as I go and when I need to retrieve some data via the python script it will always be up to date.

If anybody can point out something I've done wrong or could perhaps improve, please leave a comment!!